# Actualizar tabla mysql a partir de un dataframe python, sin bucle

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

Dispongo de una tabla en mysql con esta estructura
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y deseo modificar la columna "hoy" de algunos registros a partir de los datos de un dataframe en python, que contiene los registros que se tienen que modificar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sé hacerlo con un bucle y haciendo un UPDATE  de cada registro, pero me gustaría saber si existe alguna manera de modificarlos de golpe todos a partir de ese dataframe. Pero tan sólo los que haya que modificar, sin tener que borrar la tabla o hacer un bucle.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: La verdad... no se me ocurre nada que sea mas simple que bucle. ¿Cual sería el problema de hacerlo con un bucle?

Comment: Muy lento y muchos accesos. Tal vez, pienso que podría existir algo como el to_sql de pandas. Es que cuando son miles de registros la cosa se ralentiza bastante

Comment: Hacer varios `UPDATE` individuales es más lento que un `UPDATE` único, aunque éste afecte a tantos datos como el conjunto de los individuales. Lo que sí puedes hacer es construirte una query única con un bucle y ejecutarla posteriormente. Tal vez te refieras a eso. Incluye tu código para ayudarte con más detalle.

Comment: A eso me refiero David, pero no sé muy bien cómo hacerlo. A ver si puedo incluir el código, porque los UPDATE serían sobre miles de registros de entre millones que hay en la tabla

Comment: @evalde lento? como estas midiendo la velocidad? Usas sentencias preparadas? Otra idea, es crear una tabla temporal, insertar todos los datos del dataframe y hacer un UPDATE uniendo ambas tablas... pero no estoy muy seguro de que sea "más rápdio" y ni hablar que es "mas enrosacado"

Comment: @Marcos, sí perdona, me despisté: donde dije `UPDATE` quería decir `INSERT`. Subes todos los datos en unos pocos `INSERT` y después los actualizas con un `UPDATE tabla JOIN tabla_temporal ...` Lo que se hace eterno es mediante `INSERT` individuales

Comment: @DavidJP, estoy de acuerdo que hacer INSERT individuales es lento, pero tampoco podes hacer un INSERT de miles de registros, por lo que tendrías que "paginar" los INSERT para evitar fallos. La tabla temporal que debe ser creada con el formato correcto para que al realizar el UPDATE uniendo ambas tablas se utilicen indices. Finalmente llegamos a las condiciones establecidas por el OP, donde dice _"[...] sin tener que borrar la tabla o hacer un bucle"_. Hacer esto implica realizar ambas cosas jajajaja

Comment: @Marcos, pues razón no te falta, aunque su tabla original sólo se toca con el `UPDATE`, la que se borra es la auxiliar... Además, uno es lo que se pide y otro lo que realmente se necesita... De lo que no hay duda es que, con esta solución, se ahorrará mucho tiempo volcando los datos por muchas páginas que tenga que hacer... :)

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que en pandas no tengas dificultades, te propongo el siguiente ejemplo mínimo viable:

```
lista=[
    ['dato1','dato2'],
    ['datp3','dato4']
]
sql='INSERT INTO tabla_temporal (campo1,campo2) VALUES '
for i in lista:
    sql+="('"+i[0]+"','"+i[1]+"'),"
sql=sql[:-1]+';'
print(sql)
```

Y, con los datos en la tabla temporal, ya podrías hacer:

```
UPDATE tabla t
    JOIN tabla_temporal tt USING(campo1)
    SET t.campo2=tt.campo2;
```

Espero que te resulte útil. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Probaré lo de la tabla temporal y si no es más rápido, haré lo del bucle. Os diré lo que hago finalmente. Gracias!

Comment: Tendría que ser un "INNER JOIN" para evitar establecer en NULL los registros que no estan en la tabla temporal

Comment: @Marcos, en MySQL el `JOIN` y el `INNER JOIN` son equivalentes. Sería con un `LEFT JOIN` con el que obtendríamos el resultado que comentas

Comment: Interensante! No lo sabia  :)

Comment: @evalde Por favor, indícanos si esta respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Comment: Muchas gracias. Al final utilicé la creación de una tabla temporal, actualizando la principal con un JOIN. El bucle con un UPDATE por cada registro era más lento. La tabla temporal la creé a partir de un dataframe que pasé con to_sql de pandas